# create a new dict based on old dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I am have the following dict:

```
abc = {"type":"insecure","id":"1","name":"peter"}
```

what I want to do is to have a new dict based on the old dict in which there is no key "type" and key "id" is changed to "identity". The new dict will look as follows:

```
xyz = {"identity":"1","name":"peter"}
```

The solution that I came up was as follows:

```
abc = {"type":"insecure","id":"1","name":"peter"}
xyz = {}
black_list_values = set(("type","id"))
for k in abc:
    if k not in blacklist_values:
        xyz[k] = abc[k]
xyz["identity"] = abc["id"]
```

I was wondering if its the fastest and efficient way to do that? Right now, "abc" have only three values. If "abc" is much bigger and have many values then is my solution still the efficient and fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a dict-comprehension:

```
abc = {"type":"insecure","id":"1","name":"peter"}
black_list = {"type"}
rename ={"id":"identity"}  #use a mapping dictionary in case you want to rename multiple items
dic = {rename.get(key,key) : val for key ,val in abc.items() if key not in black_list}
print dic
```

**output:**

```
{'name': 'peter', 'identity': '1'}
```

Comment: I am wondering about one thing in your solution. Is it a good idea to do the following in your solution. black_list = {"type"} wont it be better with list?

Comment: @yasra002 NO, searching in lists takes `O(N)` time, while  sets take `O(1)` time.

Answer (score 8):

You want to create a new dictionary anyway. You can iterate over keys/values in a dict comprehension, which is more compact, but functionally the same:

```
abc = {"type":"insecure","id":"1","name":"peter"}

black_list_values = set(("type","id"))

xyz = {k:v for k,v in abc.iteritems() if k not in black_list_values}
xyz["identity"] = abc["id"]
```

Comment: thanks for that. If I dont create a new  dictionary then then just modify the "abc" then what will be the best option in that case. I am getting "abc" from "redis" and was wondering if it will be good idea to create  new dictionary  or somehow modify the "abc" Here is how I am getting the "abc" abc = redis.hgetall("some_hash_value")

Answer (score 5):

Without iterating through the original dict:

```
abc = {"type":"insecure","id":"1","name":"peter"}
xyz = abc.copy()
xyz.pop('type')
xyz['identity'] = xyz.pop('id')
```

Comment: It is important to note, that `.copy()` creates a shallow copy of the original dictionary. If the original one points to lists/dicts/sets, the new one will point to the same objects.

Comment: And so for .iteritems() and other methods. If you don't use deepcopy, then "everything" is shallow-copied.

Answer (score 2):

If all the keys are pre-known and it's a short list of keys, then the obvious solution is just

```
xyz = {"identity":abc["id"],"name":abc["name"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

A another simple suggestion would be to use the `dict()` function:

```
abc = {"type":"insecure","id":"1","name":"peter"}
xyz = dict(abc)
```

Then perform the replacement in any way you see fit =-)